# Excel Services Service Application

Tags: service-application

I have just installed SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition and now I am trying to create the new Excel and Access Service Applications. I am having two issues:

1. When I click on New service application and chose Excel Service Application, it will just sit there spinning and is never done.
2. When I close the modal popup, Excel Services Service Application is created by the status shows 'Stopped'. How do I start it?!

I am certain something is wrong but there is no error message for me track it down. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Technet has a great guide for [Configuring Excel Sevices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219698.aspx).

I think this is the step you have missed:

> Start the Excel Calculation Services service
>
> In order to use Excel
> Services, you must start the Excel Calculation Services service on at
> least one application server in the farm. Use the following procedure
> to start the service.
>
> To start the Excel Calculation Services service
>
> 1. On the Central Administration home page, in the System Settings
>    section, click Manage services on server.
> 2. To select the server where
>    you want to start the service, above the Service list, click the
>    Server drop-down list, and then click Change Server and choose the
>    appropriate server.
> 3. In the Service list, click Start next to Excel
>    Calculation Services.
> 4. After the Excel Calculation Services service has
>    been started, the next step is to create an Excel Services service
>    application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I forgot to mention but I did start the Excel Calculation Service before creating Service Application. My problem is I am not seeing any error - Service Application is created but the status indicates as 'Stopped'

Comment: I have followed the instructions from the above link except I did not create a new account for the application pool and instead used a generic one.

Comment: I'm hitting same exact issue, and calculation services was started...

Answer (score 2):

Try to start the Timer Service on the SP App server.  I was getting the exact same behavior when trying to create the Excel Service App.  The ULS logs on the SP server kept noting the following:

> SPTimerJobAsyncResult Timer job has not completed.  Blocking until job
>   completes.

Once I started the timer service, the App installed with the proxy.

Hope this helps.